# Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

**Cannot use the ROLLBACK statement within an INSERT-EXEC statement**

I am using two stored procedures. the first sp returns some int value

I am using this in the second sp with **INSERT EXEC**

But when i am executing the second sp , I am getting the above error

Please help

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code of the second stored procedure?